# SQL Server : query for comma separated with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one for country an the other for the city, and I want a query to get the country with all the cities in a comma-separated which grouped by the countries.

***Note:***

1. The second table has a foreign key `Fk_CountryId` from the primary key of the first table `CityId` which is a primary key
2. I am using SQL Server

The first table `Country` looks like this

```
CountryId | CountryName 
----------+-------------
    1     | USA 
    2     | UK
    3     | Germany
```

The second table `City` looks like this

```
CityId | CityName   | Fk_CountryId
-------+------------+-------
1      | Los Angeles|   1
2      | Boston     |   1
3      | Cambridge  |   2
4      | Chester    |   2
5      | Berlin     |   3
6      | Hamburg    |   3
```

The expected DataSet:

```
CountryId | CountryName  | CitiesNames
----------+--------------+----------------------
1         | USA          | Los Angeles, Boston
2         | UK           | Cambridge, Chester
3         | Germany      | Berlin, Hamburg
```

Comment: Foreign keys are there to ensure data consistency.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `SELECT C.CountryId,C.CountryName, STRING_AGG(Ci,CityName, ', ') AS CitiesNames
FROM Country C
INNER JOIN City Ci
 ON C.CountryId = Ci.Fk_CountryId
GROUP BY C.CountryId,C.CountryName;`

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older version of SQL Server i would use `FOR XML` clause with `STUFF()` :

```
SELECT c.CountryId, c.CountryName,
       STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ' ,'+ct.CityName   
               FROM City ct
               WHERE ct.CountryId = c.CountryId 
               FOR XML PATH ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) AS CitiesNames
FROM Country c;
```

You can use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for newer version (SQL Server 2017). However, `DISTINCT` is redundant inside `STUFF()` if you don't have a duplicate cities. So, you can remove it.

For better performance you need index `Country (CountryId)` include `CountryName`, `CityName`.

Comment: and what about new version of sql server because i want the performance here

Comment: @AhmedRamadan [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: but I  see unexpected characters like this      ,Masaken Sheraton - Sun City&#x0D;
 ,Mohandiseen&#x0D;